# Git Clone ssh authentication through bash script

Tags: bash, github

I'm using Raspbian.

I did successfully added the key and I can clone a private repo with ssh auth manually, using the command `git clone git@github.com:USER/repo.git`.

Here is how I set it up:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096 -C “email”
eval "$(ssh-agent -s)"
ssh-add -k ~/.ssh/id_rsa
cat ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
```

However, if I try to run git clone command through a bash script, I get `Permission denied (publickey).`

I'm running the script as "pi", with sudo. The script starts with `#! /bin/bash` and `whoami` (on the script) returns `root`, instead of "pi".

Could someone help me out, please?

Thanks!

Comment: Are you running the script manually as root?

Comment: @ScottBro, I think so, as I'm using "sudo ./script.sh"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

SSH attemps to read the keys from `$HOME/.ssh`. Since you are running as `root`, the script most likely fails to find anything under `/home/root/.ssh`.

The fix? Try `sudo -E`, which preserves the environment variables. For more info, consult [sudo(8)](https://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo).

Comment: Awesome! It worked. Is there a way to set the "-E" option inside the script, so user would just run the script with "sudo ./script.sh"?

Thanks!

Comment: I have `sudo -E` as an alias for myself. It is not recommended to elevate privileges in a script. It violates the principle of "least surprise". If this solves your problem, please mark the answer as accepted ;-)